# How can I fix This 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?

Tags: python, phpmyadmin

I would like to ask an question like this It makes me Struggle. Please Help

How Can I Fix This error While Updating the Table

Here's The code

Heres The Update Code

```
def update():
        databases = mysql.connector.connect(
        host ="localhost",
        user = "userdata",
        password = "",
        database = "facerecog"
        )
        conn = databases.cursor()
        conn.execute("UPDATE record set names=%s, course_year=%s, position=%s"(t4.get(),t5.get(),t6.get()))
        databases.commit
        databases.close
        messagebox.showinfo("NOTICE", "UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY")
```

And here The data show Selected Shows on my text box

```
    def showtable(tree):
        viewinfo = tree.focus()
        data = tree.item(viewinfo)
        row = data['values']
        t4.set(row[0])
        t5.set(row[1])
        t6.set(row[2])
```

And Here's The button

```
    updatebutton = tk.Button(t, text = "Update Data", command =update)
    updatebutton.configure(font = ('Cooper', 13, 'bold'), bg = 'sky blue', fg = 'black')
    updatebutton.place(x=560, y=360)
    t.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",showtable)
```

And then It Appears error Like this

```
py:347: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  conn.execute("UPDATE record set names=%s, course_year=%s, position=%s"(t4.get(),t5.get(),t6.get()))
```

Comment: The error is telling you what to fix: it seems like you have invalid format.  `%s"(t4` that format is certainly invalid. you need to replace it like `%s", t4`

Comment: @rv.kvetch Write that as an answer and I'll upvote it; it is better than the other two answers at the moment which both invite SQL injection headaches. Edit: Hm, or I'll just vote to close the whole thing as trivial...

Comment: @TurePålsson done :-)

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you what to fix: it seems like you have invalid format.

The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) that I was able to find for the `mysql.connector` seems to confirm that you would separate formatted arguments with a comma `,` as I had initially suspected. By the way, the log methods in the python `logging` module  work the same way as well, which is pretty handy.

So in your case, I'd replace that line:

```
conn.execute(update_stmt(t4.get(),t5.get(),t6.get()))
```

where `update_stmt` is defined as

```
"UPDATE record set names=%s, course_year=%s, position=%s"
```

with the following line:

```
conn.execute(update_stmt, (t4.get(),t5.get(),t6.get()))
```

---

As an aside, you'll have noticed that the error you got is actually very helpful in this case:

```
py:347: SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
```

Which is actually the very thing we needed to do to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be a string formatting, it is missing `%`:

```
conn.execute("UPDATE record set names=%s, course_year=%s, position=%s" % (t4.get(),t5.get(),t6.get()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Modulo string formatting is kind of ancient, I prefer f-strings:

```
conn.execute(f"UPDATE record set names={t4.get()}, course_year={t5.get()}, position={t6.get()}")
```